# Novel or lesser known data structures for network (graph) data?

Tags: language-agnostic, optimization, data-structures, graph, complexity-theory

What are some more interesting [graph data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29) for working with networks?   I am interested in structures which may offer some particular advantage in terms of traversing the network, finding random nodes, size in memory or for insertion/deletion/temporary hiding of nodes for example.

Note: I'm not so much interested in database like designs for addressing external memory problems.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but you might find some good stuff here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500607/what-are-the-lesser-known-but-cool-data-structures

Answer (score 2):

One of my personal favorites is the [link/cut tree](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/dynamic-trees.pdf), a data structure for partitioning a graph into a family of directed trees.  This lets you solve network flow problems asymptotically faster than more traditional methods and can be used as a more powerful generalization of the union/find structure you may have heard of before.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of Skip Graphs ( http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=skip+graphs ), a probabilistic graph structure that is - as far as I know - already in use in some peer-to-peer applications.

These graphs are kind of self-organizing and their goal is to achieve a good connectivity and a small diameter. There is a distributed algorithm that tries to achieve such graphs: http://www14.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/personen/jacob/Publications/podc09.pdf