# Writing Visual Studio App.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I recently found myself writing some XML in my Visual Studio 2010 Project's `App.config` file.

The values I used were `assemblyIdentity` and `bindingRedirect` - neither of which show up using [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense).

I'd like to know some cool tricks that other developers have come up with to use in `App.config` - a file I rarely touch.

There's a document on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x77e536.aspx) (+1 for other links), but it (most likely) will not go into detail on how to do some trick stuff.

**[Update]**

Due to the fact that [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57135/joe), [djacobson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238688/djacobson), [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman), [Mark Biek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305/mark-biek), and [Neil Knight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410636/neil-knight) collectively voted to close my question, I've decided to post a couple of examples of the kinds of info I'm looking for:

- [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033)
- [What are the lesser known but cool data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500607)

Comment: Can you make your question a little more specific? What sorts of tricks are you looking for?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read

Comment: Wait, what does that question have to do with app.configs? :)

Comment: The guy is looking for techniques and ideas. Same here. Vote to reopen, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to start with:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/09/tricks-with-app-config-and-clickonce-deployment-saurabh-bhatia.aspx

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have the required permission to vote for a re-open.

Comment: Well, since the goobers have closed this, I will award you the answer. I was hoping for more, but I can get some mileage out of this.