# Implement Stack using Two Queues

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

A similar question was asked earlier [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192/using-stack-as-queue), but the question here is the reverse of it, using two queues as a stack.  The question...

Given two queues with their standard operations (`enqueue`, `dequeue`, `isempty`, `size`), implement a stack with its standard operations (`pop`, `push`, `isempty`, `size`).

There should be **two** versions of the solution.

- Version **A**: The stack should be efficient when pushing an item; and
- Version **B**: The stack should be efficient when popping an item.

I am interested in the algorithm more than any specific language implementations.  However, I welcome solutions expressed in languages which I am familiar ([java](/questions/tagged/java),[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23),[python](/questions/tagged/python),[vb](/questions/tagged/vb),[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript),[php](/questions/tagged/php)).

Comment: Sure it is! CLRS - 10.1-6 (http://tinyurl.com/clrs-ex-10-1-6)

Comment: [One Stack, Two Queues](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/one-stack-two-queues/2589#2589) gives an elegant solution in which `Pop` works in $O(1)$ and `Push` works in $O(\sqrt{n})$ amortized time.

Comment: @rampion Now its CLRS - 10.1-7. :)

Comment: Related post. This is one another interesting problem to implement stack using *only one* queue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4039124/465053).

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Version A (efficient push):

- push:

  - enqueue in queue1
- pop:

  - while size of queue1 is bigger than 1, pipe dequeued items from queue1 into queue2
  - dequeue and return the last item of queue1, then switch the names of queue1 and queue2

Version B (efficient pop):

- push:

  - enqueue in queue2
  - enqueue all items of queue1 in queue2, then switch the names of queue1 and queue2
- pop:

  - deqeue from queue1

Comment: Version B seems having problem: do you mean enqueue all items of queue2 to queue1 except the last element (then switch the names of q1 and q2)?

Comment: The comment of Icerman makes sense to me. The Version B of the answer needs an edit. I do not have edit permissions. Could someone please edit this answer?

Comment: @eeerahul:  I have checked it again, and the answer is correct.  At the time Icerman seems to want to enqueue all items of queue2 into queue1, queue2 consists only of the new item, so the comment does _not_ make sense.

Comment: Is Version A right? push 1, push 2, push 3, push 4. pop 4. push 5, push 6, push 7, push 8. pop 8. pop 7. Seems like that algorithm will be popping 3 instead of 7. Your algorithm seems right on first glance because we can possibly reason as: basically you will always be popping the last enqueued element in Queue 1. But that is the last pushed element only if you had queued earlier. If you popped multiple times in succession, that need not be true.

Comment: @user127.0.0.1: It seems that you forgot to switch the queues at the end of each pop.  There is an invariant that after each push and each pop, all items are in queue1, while queue2 is empty.

Comment: Version B would not support a peek operation in O(1) time unless the queue supports peeking on the last input (not common), whereas version A would O(1) peek time, assuming the queue supported peeking on the output (more common).

Comment: is it possible to have sublinear pop time (O(logn) or O(1)) with version A type enqueue?

Comment: @heyNow: See the comments to the question for a link to something like that.

Comment: I don't think versionA can support peek operation, right?

Comment: @user268451: it's just like pop, except that you do not delete the last item but reenqueue it in queue2 (before the switch).

Answer (score 68):

The easiest (and maybe only) way of doing this is by pushing new elements into the empty queue, and then dequeuing the other and enqeuing into the previously empty queue. With this way the latest is always at the front of the queue. This would be version B, for version A you just reverse the process by dequeuing the elements into the second queue except for the last one.

Step 0:

```
"Stack"
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

Queue A                Queue B
+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Step 1:

```
"Stack"
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

Queue A                Queue B
+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 |   |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Step 2:

```
"Stack"
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 1 |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

Queue A                Queue B
+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |  | 2 | 1 |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Step 3:

```
"Stack"
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | 2 | 1 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

Queue A                Queue B
+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | 2 | 1 |   |   |  |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: The logic for this doesn't make any sense. Take moving from Step 2 to Step 3. When I "push" 3, how can I dequeue elements in Queue B in such a way that I get 3 2 1 in Queue A? If I dequeue B to enqueue A, I can only get elements in order 2, 1. If I then add 3, I will get the order 3, 1, 2. If put my push first, and then dequeue/enqueue, I get 1, 2, 3.

Comment: why not make the deque operation expensive than making the enqueue operation expensive?

Answer (score 50):

We can do this with one queue:

push:

1. enqueue new element.
2. If `n` is the number of elements in the queue, then remove and insert element `n-1` times.

pop:

1. dequeue

.

```
push 1


front                     
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1  |    |    |    |    |    |    insert 1
+----+----+----+----+----+----+


push2

front                     
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  |    |    |    |    |    insert 2
+----+----+----+----+----+----+

     front                     
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    | 2  |  1 |    |    |    |    remove and insert 1
+----+----+----+----+----+----+




 insert 3


      front                     
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    | 2  |  1 |  3 |    |    |    insert 3
+----+----+----+----+----+----+

           front                     
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |  1 |  3 |  2 |    |    remove and insert 2
+----+----+----+----+----+----+

                front                     
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |  3 |  2 |  1 |    remove and insert 1
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Sample implementation:

```
int stack_pop (queue_data *q)
{
  return queue_remove (q);
}

void stack_push (queue_data *q, int val)
{
  int old_count = queue_get_element_count (q), i;

  queue_insert (q, val);
  for (i=0; i<old_count; i++)
  {
    queue_insert (q, queue_remove (q));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Mahmood
 */
public class StackImplUsingQueues {

    Queue<Integer> q1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Queue<Integer> q2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public int pop() {
        if (q1.peek() == null) {
            System.out.println("The stack is empty, nothing to return");
            int i = 0;
            return i;
        } else {
            int pop = q1.remove();
            return pop;
        }
    }

    public void push(int data) {

        if (q1.peek() == null) {
            q1.add(data);
        } else {
            for (int i = q1.size(); i > 0; i--) {
                q2.add(q1.remove());
            }
            q1.add(data);
            for (int j = q2.size(); j > 0; j--) {
                q1.add(q2.remove());
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackImplUsingQueues s1 = new StackImplUsingQueues();
        //       Stack s1 = new Stack();
        s1.push(1);
        s1.push(2);
        s1.push(3);
        s1.push(4);
        s1.push(5);
        s1.push(6);
        s1.push(7);
        s1.push(8);
        s1.push(9);
        s1.push(10);
        // s1.push(6);
        System.out.println("1st = " + s1.pop());
        System.out.println("2nd = " + s1.pop());
        System.out.println("3rd = " + s1.pop());
        System.out.println("4th = " + s1.pop());
        System.out.println("5th = " + s1.pop());
        System.out.println("6th = " + s1.pop());
        System.out.println("7th = " + s1.pop());
        System.out.println("8th = " + s1.pop());
        System.out.println("9th = " + s1.pop());
        System.out.println("10th= " + s1.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could anyone explain the login behind the push method in the code above? As far as I understood, the first for loop is removing all the elements into q2 until q1 has one element remaining. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Can we just use one queue to implement a stack? I can use two queues, but considering single queue would be more efficient. Here is the code:

```
    public void Push(T val)
    {
        queLower.Enqueue(val);
    }

    public  T Pop()
    {

        if (queLower.Count == 0 )
        {
            Console.Write("Stack is empty!");
            return default(T);

         }
        if (queLower.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < queLower.Count - 1;i++ )
            {
                queLower.Enqueue(queLower.Dequeue ());
           }
                    }

        return queLower.Dequeue();

    }
```

Comment: I guess in pop method, the for loop condition should be **i < queLower.Count - 2** as you are initialising the variable i with 0.

Answer (score 3):

```
queue<int> q1, q2;
int i = 0;

void push(int v) {
  if( q1.empty() && q2.empty() ) {
     q1.push(v);
     i = 0;
  }
  else {
     if( i == 0 ) {
        while( !q1.empty() ) q2.push(q1.pop());
        q1.push(v);
        i = 1-i;
     }
     else {
        while( !q2.empty() ) q1.push(q2.pop());
        q2.push(v);
        i = 1-i;
     }
  }
}

int pop() {
   if( q1.empty() && q2.empty() ) return -1;
   if( i == 1 ) {
      if( !q1.empty() )
           return q1.pop();
      else if( !q2.empty() )
           return q2.pop();
   }
   else {
      if( !q2.empty() )
           return q2.pop();
      else if( !q1.empty() )
           return q1.pop();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer - where the 'pop' is inefficient.
Seems that all algorithms that come immediately to mind have N complexity, where N is the size of the list: whether you choose to do work on the 'pop' or do work on the 'push'

The algorithm where lists are traded back and fourth may be better, 
 as a size calculation is not needed, although you still need to loop and compare with empty.

you can prove this algorithm cannot be written faster than N by noting that the information about the last element in a queue is only available through knowing the size of the queue, and that you must destroy data to get to that element, hence the 2nd queue.

The only way to make this faster is to not to use queues in the first place.

```
from data_structures import queue

class stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        q1= queue 
        q2= queue #only contains one item at most. a temp var. (bad?)

    def push(self, item):
        q1.enque(item) #just stick it in the first queue.

    #Pop is inefficient
    def pop(self):
        #'spin' the queues until q1 is ready to pop the right value. 
        for N 0 to self.size-1
            q2.enqueue(q1.dequeue)
            q1.enqueue(q2.dequeue)
        return q1.dequeue()

    @property
    def size(self):
        return q1.size + q2.size

    @property
    def isempty(self):
        if self.size > 0:
           return True
        else
           return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution that works for O(1) in average case. There are two queues: `in` and `out`. See pseudocode bellow:

```
PUSH(X) = in.enqueue(X)

POP: X =
  if (out.isEmpty and !in.isEmpty)
    DUMP(in, out)
  return out.dequeue

DUMP(A, B) =
  if (!A.isEmpty)
    x = A.dequeue()
    DUMP(A, B)
    B.enqueue(x)
```

Comment: There you are using 2 queues and 1 stack to simulate 1 stack!

Comment: Do you mean implict recursion stack?

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, wouldn't a single queue do the trick? It's probably less practical but is a bit slicker.

```
push(x):
enqueue(x)
for(queueSize - 1)
   enqueue(dequeue())

pop(x):
dequeue()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple pseudo code, push is O(n), pop / peek is O(1):

```
Qpush = Qinstance()
Qpop = Qinstance()

def stack.push(item):
    Qpush.add(item)
    while Qpop.peek() != null: //transfer Qpop into Qpush
        Qpush.add(Qpop.remove()) 
    swap = Qpush
    Qpush = Qpop
    Qpop = swap

def stack.pop():
    return Qpop.remove()

def stack.peek():
    return Qpop.peek()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let S1 and S2 be the two Stacks to be used in the implementation of queues.

```
struct Stack 
{ struct Queue *Q1;
  struct Queue *Q2;
}
```

We make sure that one queue is empty always.

**Push operation :**
Whichever queue is not empty, insert the element in it.

- Check whether queue Q1 is empty or not. If Q1 is empty then Enqueue the element in it.
- Otherwise EnQueue the element into Q1.

`Push (struct Stack *S, int data)
    { 
    if(isEmptyQueue(S->Q1)
         EnQueue(S->Q2, data);
    else EnQueue(S->Q1, data);
    }`

Time Complexity: O(1)

**Pop Operation:** Transfer n-1 elements to other queue and delete last from queue for performing pop operation.

- If queue Q1 is not empty then transfer n-1 elements from Q1 to Q2 and then, DeQueue the last element of Q1 and return it.
- If queue Q2 is not empty then transfer n-1 elements from Q2 to Q1 and then, DeQueue the last element of Q2 and return it.

`

```
int Pop(struct Stack *S){
int i, size;
if(IsEmptyQueue(S->Q2)) 
{
size=size(S->Q1);
i=0;
while(i<size-1)
{ EnQueue(S->Q2, Dequeue(S->Q1)) ;
  i++;
}
return DeQueue(S->Q1);  
}
else{
size=size(S->Q2);
while(i<size-1)
EnQueue(S->Q1, Dequeue(S->Q2)) ;
i++;
}
return DeQueue(S->Q2);
} }
```

Time Complexity: Running Time of pop Operation is O(n) as each time pop is called, we are transferring all the elements from one queue to oter.

Answer (score 1):

```
Q1 = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
Q2 = []

exp:
{   
    dequeue n-1 element from Q1 and enqueue into Q2: Q2 == [10, 15, 20, 25]

    now Q1 dequeue gives "30" that inserted last and working as stack
}

swap Q1 and Q2 then GOTO exp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class MyStack {
    Queue<Integer> queue1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Queue<Integer> queue2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    // Push element x onto stack.
    public void push(int x) {
        if(isEmpty()){
            queue1.offer(x);
        }else{
            if(queue1.size()>0){
                queue2.offer(x);
                int size = queue1.size();
                while(size>0){
                    queue2.offer(queue1.poll());
                    size--;
                }
            }else if(queue2.size()>0){
                queue1.offer(x);
                int size = queue2.size();
                while(size>0){
                    queue1.offer(queue2.poll());
                    size--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Removes the element on top of the stack.
    public void pop() {
        if(queue1.size()>0){
            queue1.poll();
        }else if(queue2.size()>0){
            queue2.poll();
        }
    }

    // Get the top element. You can make it more perfect just example
    public int top() {
       if(queue1.size()>0){
            return queue1.peek();
        }else if(queue2.size()>0){
            return queue2.peek();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Return whether the stack is empty.
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return queue1.isEmpty() && queue2.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more solution:

for PUSH : 
-Add first element in queue 1.
-When adding second element and so on,
 Enqueue the element in queue 2 first and then copy all the element from queue 1 to queue2. 
-for POP just dequeue the element from the queue from you inserted the last element.

So,

```
public void push(int data){
if (queue1.isEmpty()){
    queue1.enqueue(data);
}  else {
queue2.enqueue(data);
while(!queue1.isEmpty())
Queue2.enqueue(queue1.dequeue());
//EXCHANGE THE NAMES OF QUEUE 1 and QUEUE2
```

}
    }

```
public int pop(){
int popItem=queue2.dequeue();
return popItem;
}'
```

There is one problem, I am not able to figure out, how to rename the queues???

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
queue<int>Q;
stack<int>Stk;
void PRINT(stack<int>ss , queue<int>qq) {
    while( ss.size() ) {
        cout << ss.top() << " " ;
        ss.pop();
    }
    puts("");
    while( qq.size() ) {
        cout << qq.front() << " " ;
        qq.pop();
    }
    puts("\n----------------------------------");
}
void POP() {
    queue<int>Tmp ;
    while( Q.size() > 1 ) {
        Tmp.push( Q.front()  );
        Q.pop();
    }
    cout << Q.front() << " " << Stk.top() << endl;
    Q.pop() , Stk.pop() ;
    Q = Tmp ;
}
void PUSH(int x ) {
    Q.push(x);
    Stk.push(x);
}
int main() {
    while( true ) {
        string typ ;
        cin >> typ ;
        if( typ == "push" ) {
            int x ;
            cin >> x;
            PUSH(x);
        } else POP();
        PRINT(Stk,Q);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please some words, explaining what this code is about, and how this thingy is able to help the OP in solving his/her problem, will be highly appreciated, along with the code example :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Python Code Using Only One Queue**

```
 class Queue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
    def enqueue(self,item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)
    def dequeue(self):
        if(not self.isEmpty()):
            return  self.items.pop()
    def isEmpty(self):
        return  self.items==[]
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)



class stack(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.q1= Queue()


        def push(self, item):
            self.q1.enqueue(item) 


        def pop(self):
            c=self.q1.size()
            while(c>1):
                self.q1.enqueue(self.q1.dequeue())
                c-=1
            return self.q1.dequeue()



        def size(self):
            return self.q1.size() 


        def isempty(self):
            if self.size > 0:
               return True
            else:
               return False
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping a code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.

Answer (score 0):

**here is the complete working code in c# :**

It has been implemented with Single Queue,

push:

```
1. add new element.
2. Remove elements from Queue (totalsize-1) times and add back to the Queue
```

pop:

```
normal remove





 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace StackImplimentationUsingQueue
    {
        class Program
        {
            public class Node
            {
                public int data;
                public Node link;
            }
            public class Queue
            {
                public Node rear;
                public Node front;
                public int size = 0;
                public void EnQueue(int data)
                {
                    Node n = new Node();
                    n.data = data;
                    n.link = null;
                    if (rear == null)
                        front = rear = n;
                    else
                    {
                        rear.link = n;
                        rear = n;
                    }
                    size++;
                    Display();
                }
                public Node DeQueue()
                {
                    Node temp = new Node();
                    if (front == null)
                        Console.WriteLine("Empty");
                    else
                    {
                        temp = front;
                        front = front.link;
                        size--;
                    }
                    Display();
                    return temp;
                }
                public void Display()
                {
                    if (size == 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Empty");
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Node n = front;
                        while (n != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(n.data);
                            n = n.link;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            public class Stack
            {
                public Queue q;
                public int size = 0;
                public Node top;
                public Stack()
                {
                    q = new Queue();
                }
                public void Push(int data)
                {
                    Node n = new Node();
                    n.data = data;
                    q.EnQueue(data);
                    size++;
                    int counter = size;
                    while (counter > 1)
                    {
                        q.EnQueue(q.DeQueue().data);
                        counter--;
                    }
                }
                public void Pop()
                {
                    q.DeQueue();
                    size--;
                }
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Stack s= new Stack();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                    s.Push(i);
                for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
                    s.Pop();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Care to comment on the (expected/amortised) time require by your implementation as a function of the elements currently kept/sum of pushes&pops?

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple solution which uses one Queue and gives functionality like Stack.

```
public class CustomStack<T>
{
    Queue<T> que = new Queue<T>();

    public void push(T t) // STACK = LIFO / QUEUE = FIFO
    {

        if( que.Count == 0)
        {
            que.Enqueue(t);
        }
        else
        {
            que.Enqueue(t);
            for (int i = 0; i < que.Count-1; i++)
            {
                var data = que.Dequeue();

                que.Enqueue(data);
            }
        }

    }

    public void pop()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("\nStack Implementation:");
        foreach (var item in que)
        {
            Console.Write("\n" + item.ToString() + "\t");
        }

        var data = que.Dequeue();
        Console.Write("\n Dequeing :" + data);
    }

    public void top()
    {

        Console.Write("\n Top :" + que.Peek());
    }


}
```

So in the above class named "CustomStack" what I am doing is just checking the queue for empty , if empty then insert one and from then on wards insert and then remove insert. By this logic first will come last.
Example : In queue I inserted 1 and now trying to insert 2. Second time remove 1 and again insert so it becomes in reverse order.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very simple Java solution which supports the push operation efficient.

**Algorithm -**

1. Declare two Queues q1 and q2.
2. Push operation - Enqueue element to queue q1.
3. Pop operation - Ensure that queue q2 is not empty. If it is empty,
   then dequeue all the elements from q1 except the last element and
   enqueue it to q2 one by one. Dequeue the last element from q1 and
   store it as the popped element. Swap the queues q1 and q2. Return
   the stored popped element.
4. Peek operation - Ensure that queue q2 is not empty. If it is empty,
   then dequeue all the elements from q1 except the last element and
   enqueue it to q2 one by one. Dequeue the last element from q1 and
   store it as the peeked element. Enqueue it back to queue q2 and swap
   the queues q1 and q2. Return the stored peeked element.

Below is the code for above algorithm -

```
class MyStack {

    java.util.Queue<Integer> q1;
    java.util.Queue<Integer> q2;
    int SIZE = 0;

    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    public MyStack() {
        q1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        q2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    }

    /** Push element x onto stack. */
    public void push(int x) {
        q1.add(x);
        SIZE ++;

    }

    /** Removes the element on top of the stack and returns that element. */
    public int pop() {
        ensureQ2IsNotEmpty();
        int poppedEle = q1.remove();
        SIZE--;
        swapQueues();
        return poppedEle;
    }

    /** Get the top element. */
    public int top() {
        ensureQ2IsNotEmpty();
        int peekedEle = q1.remove();
        q2.add(peekedEle);
        swapQueues();
        return peekedEle;
    }

    /** Returns whether the stack is empty. */
    public boolean empty() {
        return q1.isEmpty() && q2.isEmpty();

    }

    /** move all elements from q1 to q2 except last element */
    public void ensureQ2IsNotEmpty() {
        for(int i=0; i<SIZE-1; i++) {
            q2.add(q1.remove());
        }
    }

    /** Swap queues q1 and q2 */
    public void swapQueues() {
        Queue<Integer> temp = q1;
        q1 = q2;
        q2 = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficient solution in C#

```cs
public class MyStack {
    private Queue<int> q1 = new Queue<int>();
    private Queue<int> q2 = new Queue<int>();
    private int count = 0;

    /**
     * Initialize your data structure here.
     */
    public MyStack() {
    }

    /**
     * Push element x onto stack.
     */
    public void Push(int x) {
        count++;
        q1.Enqueue(x);
        while (q2.Count > 0) {
            q1.Enqueue(q2.Peek());
            q2.Dequeue();
        }
        var temp = q1;
        q1 = q2;
        q2 = temp;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the element on top of the stack and returns that element.
     */
    public int Pop() {
        count--;
        return q2.Dequeue();
    }

    /**
     * Get the top element.
     */
    public int Top() {
        return q2.Peek();
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the stack is empty.
     */
    public bool Empty() {
        if (count > 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
class stackfmtoq {
    queue<T> q1;
    queue<T> q2;
public:
    void push(T data) {
        while (!q2.empty()) {
            q1.push(q2.front());
            q2.pop();
        }
        q2.push(data);
        while (!q1.empty()) {
            q2.push(q1.front());
            q1.pop();
        }
    }
    T pop() {
        if (q2.empty()) {
            cout << "Stack is Empty\n";
            return NULL;
        }
        T ret = q2.front();
        q2.pop();
        return ret;
    }
    T top() {
        if (q2.empty()) return NULL;
        return q2.front();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class ImplementationOfStackUsingTwoQueue {

    private static Deque<Integer> inboxQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    private static Queue<Integer> outboxQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    
    public void pushInStack(Integer val){
        inboxQueue.add(val);
    }
    
    public void popFromStack(){
        
        if(outboxQueue.isEmpty()){
            while(!inboxQueue.isEmpty()){
                outboxQueue.add(inboxQueue.pollLast());
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ImplementationOfStackUsingTwoQueue obj = new ImplementationOfStackUsingTwoQueue();
        
        obj.pushInStack(1);
        obj.pushInStack(2);
        obj.pushInStack(3);
        obj.pushInStack(4);
        obj.pushInStack(5);
        System.out.println("After pushing the values in Queue" + inboxQueue);
        
        obj.popFromStack();
        System.out.println("After popping the values from Queue" + outboxQueue);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

A different approach which is easy to understand and implement could be:

1. Add operation --> Always add elements in the empty queue and after adding that element move all other elements from other non-empty queue to this queue.
2. Pop operation --> whichever queue is not empty perform remove/poll on it and return.
3. Top operation --> Whichever queue is not empty perform peek on it and return.
4. Print --> Whichever queue is not empty print it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution..

Concept_Behind::
`push(struct Stack* S,int data)`::This function enqueue first element in Q1 and rest in Q2
`pop(struct Stack* S)`::if Q2 is not empty the transfers all elem's into Q1 and return the last elem in Q2
else(which means Q2 is empty ) transfers all elem's into Q2 and returns the last elem in Q1

Efficiency_Behind::
`push(struct Stack*S,int data)`::O(1)//since single enqueue per data
`pop(struct Stack* S)`::O(n)//since tranfers worst n-1 data per pop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Queue{
    int front;
    int rear;
    int *arr;
    int size;
    };
struct Stack {
    struct Queue *Q1;
    struct Queue *Q2;
    };
struct Queue* Qconstructor(int capacity)
{
    struct Queue *Q=malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    Q->front=Q->rear=-1;
    Q->size=capacity;
    Q->arr=malloc(Q->size*sizeof(int));
    return Q;
    }
int isEmptyQueue(struct Queue *Q)
{
    return (Q->front==-1);
    }
int isFullQueue(struct Queue *Q)
{
    return ((Q->rear+1) % Q->size ==Q->front);
    }
void enqueue(struct Queue *Q,int data)
{
    if(isFullQueue(Q))
        {
            printf("Queue overflow\n");
            return;}
    Q->rear=Q->rear+1 % Q->size;
    Q->arr[Q->rear]=data;
    if(Q->front==-1)
        Q->front=Q->rear;
        }
int dequeue(struct Queue *Q)
{
    if(isEmptyQueue(Q)){
        printf("Queue underflow\n");
        return;
        }
    int data=Q->arr[Q->front];
    if(Q->front==Q->rear)
        Q->front=-1;
    else
    Q->front=Q->front+1 % Q->size;
    return data;
    }
///////////////////////*************main algo****************////////////////////////
struct Stack* Sconstructor(int capacity)
{
    struct Stack *S=malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    S->Q1=Qconstructor(capacity);
    S->Q2=Qconstructor(capacity);
    return S;
}
void push(struct Stack *S,int data)
{
    if(isEmptyQueue(S->Q1))
        enqueue(S->Q1,data);
    else
        enqueue(S->Q2,data);
    }
int pop(struct Stack *S)
{
    int i,tmp;
    if(!isEmptyQueue(S->Q2)){
        for(i=S->Q2->front;i<=S->Q2->rear;i++){
            tmp=dequeue(S->Q2);
            if(isEmptyQueue(S->Q2))
                return tmp;
            else
                enqueue(S->Q1,tmp);
                }
            }
    else{
        for(i=S->Q1->front;i<=S->Q1->rear;i++){
            tmp=dequeue(S->Q1);
            if(isEmptyQueue(S->Q1))
                return tmp;
            else
                enqueue(S->Q2,tmp);
                }
            }
        }
////////////////*************end of main algo my algo************
///////////////*************push() O(1);;;;pop() O(n);;;;*******/////
main()
{
    int size;
    printf("Enter the number of elements in the Stack(made of 2 queue's)::\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    struct Stack *S=Sconstructor(size);
    push(S,1);
    push(S,2);
    push(S,3);
    push(S,4);
    printf("%d\n",pop(S));
    push(S,5);
    printf("%d\n",pop(S));
    printf("%d\n",pop(S));
    printf("%d\n",pop(S));
    printf("%d\n",pop(S));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;


public class StackQueue {

    static Queue<Integer> Q1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    static Queue<Integer> Q2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    public static void main(String args[]) {



        push(24);
        push(34);
        push(4);
        push(10);
        push(1);
        push(43);
        push(21);
        System.out.println("Popped element is  "+pop());
        System.out.println("Popped element is  "+pop());
        System.out.println("Popped element is  "+pop());


    }

    public static void push(int data) {

        Q1.add(data);

    }

    public static int pop() {

        if(Q1.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Cannot pop elements ,  Stack is Empty !!"); 
        return -1;
        }
        else
        {
        while(Q1.size() > 1) {
            Q2.add(Q1.remove());
        }
        int element = Q1.remove();
        Queue<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        temp = Q1;
        Q1 = Q2;
        Q2 = temp;
        return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Java linked list functions as a deque just fine. This answer does not make sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct {
    int *q;
    int size;
    int front;
    int rear;
} Queue;
typedef struct {
    Queue *q1;
    Queue *q2;
} Stack;

int queueIsEmpty(Queue *q) {
    if (q->front == -1 && q->rear == -1) {
        printf("\nQUEUE is EMPTY\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int queueIsFull(Queue *q) {
    if (q->rear == q->size-1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int queueTop(Queue *q) {
    if (queueIsEmpty(q)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return q->q[q->front];
}
int queuePop(Queue *q) {
    if (queueIsEmpty(q)) {
        return -1;
    }
    int item = q->q[q->front];
    if (q->front == q->rear) {
        q->front = q->rear = -1;
    }
    else {
        q->front++;
    }
    return item;
}
void queuePush(Queue *q, int val) {
    if (queueIsFull(q)) {
        printf("\nQUEUE is FULL\n");
        return;
    }
    if (queueIsEmpty(q)) {
        q->front++;
        q->rear++;
    } else {
        q->rear++;
    }
    q->q[q->rear] = val;
}
Queue *queueCreate(int maxSize) {
    Queue *q = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    q->front = q->rear = -1;
    q->size = maxSize;
    q->q = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*maxSize);
    return q;
}
/* Create a stack */
void stackCreate(Stack *stack, int maxSize) {
    Stack **s = (Stack**) stack;
    *s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    (*s)->q1 = queueCreate(maxSize);
    (*s)->q2 = queueCreate(maxSize);
}

/* Push element x onto stack */
void stackPush(Stack *stack, int element) {
    Stack **s = (Stack**) stack;
    queuePush((*s)->q2, element);
    while (!queueIsEmpty((*s)->q1)) {
        int item = queuePop((*s)->q1);
        queuePush((*s)->q2, item);
    }
    Queue *tmp = (*s)->q1;
    (*s)->q1 = (*s)->q2;
    (*s)->q2 = tmp;
}

/* Removes the element on top of the stack */
void stackPop(Stack *stack) {
    Stack **s = (Stack**) stack;
    queuePop((*s)->q1);
}

/* Get the top element */
int stackTop(Stack *stack) {
    Stack **s = (Stack**) stack;
    if (!queueIsEmpty((*s)->q1)) {
      return queueTop((*s)->q1);
    }
    return -1;
}

/* Return whether the stack is empty */
bool stackEmpty(Stack *stack) {
    Stack **s = (Stack**) stack;
    if (queueIsEmpty((*s)->q1)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Destroy the stack */
void stackDestroy(Stack *stack) {
    Stack **s = (Stack**) stack;
    free((*s)->q1);
    free((*s)->q2);
    free((*s));
}

int main()
{
  Stack *s = NULL;
  stackCreate((Stack*)&s, 10);
  stackPush((Stack*)&s, 44);
  //stackPop((Stack*)&s);
  printf("\n%d", stackTop((Stack*)&s));
  stackDestroy((Stack*)&s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A wall of code without comments or explanation is a poor answer.