# C Programming-Enter 3 Characters and print in reverse order

Tags: c, recursion

I'm having some trouble with this program. I think I have it almost right, besides the fact that it prints garbage to the screen :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define strsize 30

typedef struct member
{
    int number;
    char fname[strsize];
    struct member *next;
} RECORD;

RECORD* insert (RECORD *it);
RECORD* print(RECORD *it, int j);

int main (void)
{
    int i, result;
    RECORD *head, *p;
    head=NULL;
    printf("Enter the number of characters: ");
    scanf("%d", &result);

    for (i=1; i<=result; i++)
        head=insert (head);

    print (head, result);

    return 0;
}

RECORD* insert (RECORD *it)
{
    RECORD *cur, *q;
    int num;
    char junk;
    char first[strsize];
    printf("Enter a character:");
    scanf("%c", &first);

    cur=(RECORD *) malloc(sizeof(RECORD));

    strcpy(cur->fname, first);
    cur->next=NULL;

    if (it==NULL)
        it=cur;    
    else
    {
        q=it;

        while (q->next!=NULL)
            q=q->next;

        q->next=cur;
    }

    return (it);
}

RECORD* print(RECORD *it, int j)
{
    RECORD *cur;
    cur=it;
    int i;

    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
    {
        printf("%c \n", cur->fname);
        cur=cur->next;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you give us a little bit more detail about what you are trying to accomplish, instead of dumping all of the code on top of us and expecting us to debug for you? And also for future reference, you might want to get the language name correct.

Comment: My bad, it is C. And it's supposed prompt the user for 3 characters and print 3 characters in reverse order to the screen

Comment: And it should be solved with linked lists, right? Why would you use them otherwise? Its easy like "char a, b, c; cin >> a >> b >> c; cout << c << b << a".

Comment: Yes, sorry i'm very close minded when in comes to programming

Comment: @James, surely the problem description can't _just_ be _input three characters and print them in reverse order_, because you've got structures suitable for a list, stack or queue defined, dynamic memory allocation, etc. That specific problem statement is solvable in roughly ten lines of C, so what _additional_ requirements are placed on your code to make it so much more complex?

Comment: Write a program that creates a linked list of 10 characters, then creates a copy of the list in reverse order. The user should be prompted to input the characters and the program should have a print function that prints out the original list and then prints out the list in reverse order.

Comment: Sorry for the vague description, I wrote this program a while ago along with 10 others and just tested it and realized it doesn't run. My apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a quick step back; I'd like to suggest some general programming guidelines based on what I see from your code:

```
RECORD* insert (RECORD *it)
{
    RECORD *cur, *q;
    int num;
    char junk;
    char first[strsize];
    printf("Enter a character:");
    scanf("%c", &first);

    cur=(RECORD *) malloc(sizeof(RECORD));
```

An `insert()` routine on records suitable for complex datastructures is not usually expected / allowed / desired to perform user interaction; you are mingling *user interface* with *internal business logic*. (While *business logic* is a [high-falutin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/highfalutin) phrase, I don't know a better way to say "the things your program has to do in order to justify its existence" or "the essential requirements the program must satisfy". Replacement suggestions welcomed. :)

Consider this pseudo-code as a replacement algorithm:

```
while we need more characters
    prompt user for another character
    store character in datastructure
print datastructure in reverse
```

Separate all the code for the *datastructure* from the *interaction with the human*. (This separation of presentation from logic is often formalized as
[Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), but it is important to recognize that it is *not* limited to user interfaces -- you want your stack, list, or queue to be useful in your *next* programming project, so build generic routines that *only* operate on the stack, list, or queue, and you *can* reuse them in the next project.)

---

**Update**

> Write a program that creates a linked
>   list of 10 characters, then creates a
>   copy of the list in reverse order. The
>   user should be prompted to input the
>   characters and the program should have
>   a print function that prints out the
>   original list and then prints out the
>   list in reverse order

Now *this* is more like it. While I appreciate what your teacher is trying to do, a linked list isn't the datastructure I'd select for this problem. (I would pick an array if the problem size was *bounded*, a stack if the problem size was unbounded.) It's solvable with a linked list, and there are three possible approaches that come to mind immediately:

- Write a recursive output function that works like this:

  ```
  void print_output(RECORD *r) {
      if this is the last RECORD in the chain
          print the data
      else
          print_output(next record in the chain)
  }
  ```

  This uses the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) to reverse the output. Clever trick, but sometimes wastes memory compared to other approaches.
- Write your lists with doubly-linked list elements. Use both `next` and `prev` pointers, and manage them all carefully to allow you to traverse the list in either direction. This requires subtle coding and carefully thinking things through. Or copying the correct order of operations from a published source such as Knuth or your favorite algorithms text. :)
- Actually [reverse your singly-linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801549/reverse-a-singly-linked-list). Also requires subtle, careful coding or thoughtful copying. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `RECORD* print(RECORD *it, int j)` function,  you tell printf that you want to print a character but you are passing a pointer to the first element in your `fname` array, which is a memory address.

Use either:

```
printf("%s \n", cur->fname); /* print the string */
```

or

```
printf("%c \n", *cur->fname); /* print the first character */
```

I'm not sure what you want since your question is extremely vague.