# How to reverse a linked list in single for loop?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse a singly linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801549/reverse-a-singly-linked-list)

How to reverse a singly linked list in single for loop ? This was the question which was asked in an interview .

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/reverse - you don't even need a loop

Comment: thanx Mat. . . but reversing should be done without using any function like sort or reverse.

Comment: Well that's been asked & answered a lot here and elsewhere. See the second link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo code this would look like:

```
// Cache the start element
current = first;
next = current->next;
while (next != null) {
   // Cache the next pointer to not lose the reference
   temp = next->next;
   next->next = current;
   // Increment
   current = next;
   next = temp;
}
first = current;
```

I know it's not in a for loop but it can easily be rewritten to be. With the while it makes it a bit more readable.

Comment: thnx Konstantin Dinev...

Comment: I had a slight mix of this and current. It should be read as current everywhere and I edited the post.