# Reversing a singly linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reverse a singly linked list using only two pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801549/reverse-a-singly-linked-list)

This is C code to reverse a linked list. But this isn't producing the desired output.

```
struct node *temp,*prev;
while(head->next!=NULL)
  {
    temp=prev=head;
    while(temp->next->next!=NULL)
      {
    temp=temp->next;
    prev=prev->next;
      }
    temp=temp->next;
    temp->next=prev;
    prev->next=NULL;
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Consider debugging the code first...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide enough informations to have more details, so I guessed it is a singly liked list. If so, you need to run through your list once.

```
void reverse(struct node **p) {
    struct node *buff = NULL;
    struct node *head = *p;

    while (head != NULL) {
        struct node *temp = head->next;
        head->next = buff;
        buff = head;
        head = temp;
    }   

    *p = buff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will ask yourself this question often in your career, so it's important that you come up with a solution for this. Here are some pointers:

1. [Write unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code) for your code. Start with an empty list, a list with one element, then two, then three.
2. Run the code in a debugger.
3. Add debug `printf()` statements which show you what the code does as it executes.