# C: Linked list bad access of memory

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, linked-list, exc-bad-access

I have to work on linked lists and get a bad access error even before something happens in my main. I don't know what's wrong. I am relatively new to dynamic memory management. It would be nice if someone could take a look on the functions. The declaration was given by the professor, so we have to return a DoubleNote*.
My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{

    double var;

    struct node *next;


} DoubleNode;


DoubleNode* insertFirst(DoubleNode* head, double d){

    DoubleNode* new_head;
    new_head = (DoubleNode*)malloc(sizeof(DoubleNode));

    if (new_head == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Allocating memory for new node failed!");
        exit(1);
    }

    new_head->var = d;

    new_head->next = head;

    head = new_head;


    return head;

}



DoubleNode* inserLast(DoubleNode* head, double d){

    DoubleNode* current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = (DoubleNode*)malloc(sizeof(DoubleNode));
    if (current->next == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Allocating memory for new node failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
    current->next->var = d;
    current->next->next = NULL;

    return head;

}

DoubleNode* inverseDoubleListCon(DoubleNode* head){

    DoubleNode* current = head; // iteration variable starts on head of old list
    DoubleNode* conHead = current; // Head of the new list

    while (current != NULL) {

        current = current->next; //iteration step

        DoubleNode* newConHead = (DoubleNode*)malloc(sizeof(DoubleNode)); //allocating memory for new head

        if (newConHead == NULL) {
            printf("Error: Allocating memory for new node failed!");
            exit(1);
        }

        newConHead = current; // new_head is the next variable in the old list

        newConHead->next = conHead; //new head points to old head of the new list

        conHead = newConHead; // new head is set
    }


    return conHead;

}

void printList(DoubleNode* head){

    DoubleNode* current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%lf\n", current->var);
        current = current->next;
    }

}




int main(){

    DoubleNode* head = NULL;
    DoubleNode* inverseHead = NULL;
    double d;
    int i;
    int sizeOfList;

    printf("Insert amount of variables: \n");
    scanf("%d", &sizeOfList);

    for (i = 0; i < sizeOfList; i++) {
        printf("Insert variable for node [%d]: \n", i);
        scanf("%lf", &d);

        head = insertFirst(head, d);
    }

    printList(head);

    inverseHead = inverseDoubleListCon(head);

    printList(inverseHead);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What operating system are you working on?

Comment: @JohnZwinck OS X El Capitan. I'm using Xcode.

Comment: OK, so use the Xcode debugger to run your program and see where exactly it is crashing.  If you're still stuck, tell us where it crashes--which line.

Comment: `DoubleNode* head = NULL;`....`head = insertFirst(head, d);`

Comment: `sizeOfList` is not initialised before it is used in `for (i = 0; i < sizeOfList; i++)`

Comment: Above code run properly on windows. try what @BLUEPIXY have mentioned and let's us know if you are still stuck.

Comment: BTW, the last line in the function: head = new_head; doesn't change the "head" argument, its value changes only inside the function and is forgotten when the function finishes. You can just return new_head with the same result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've edited the main and now printList prints out the right result after using insertFirst. I think something in the inverseDoubleListCon is wrong. It should construct a new inverted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `sizeOfList` is not initalised. You need to add code to get the value of the size from the user.

You are also not updating the value of the head pointer from the `insertFirst` function. The code below should help.

```
DoubleNode* head= NULL;

// Code to get the value of sizeofList

for (i = 0; i < sizeOfList; i++)
{
   ...
    head = insertFirst(head, d);
}
```

The reverse function is overly complicated. You are allocating memory in `newConHead` which is not required for reversing a linked list.

I would suggest a rewrite along the lines of [How to reverse a singly linked list using only two pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801549/how-to-reverse-a-singly-linked-list-using-only-two-pointers) or http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-reverse-the-nodes-of-a-linked-list/

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed that. Such a stupid mistake.

Comment: We should implement two different functions to invert a list. One in a constructive (create new inverted list) way and the other one in a destructive way.