# Segmentation fault - display singly linked list from end to head

Tags: c, struct

I want to create with the existing singly linked list a new list but backwards.
First, print the original list, then backwards.

The progress so far:

```c
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

struct Digits {
  int digit;
  struct Digits* next;
};

void displayNodes(struct Digits*);
void freeNodes(struct Digits* );
struct Digits* backwardsList(struct Digits*, int);
struct Digits* appendNodeFront(struct Digits*, struct Digits*);
struct Digits* appendNode(struct Digits*, struct Digits*);
struct Digits* createNode(int);

int main(void) {
  int digitNodes, digits;

  struct Digits* newNode, * headNode, * endNode, * backwards;

  printf("Nodes: ");
  scanf("%d", &digitNodes);

  for(int i = 0; i < digitNodes; i++) {
    printf("Enter numebr: ");
    scanf("%d", &digits);
    newNode = createNode(digits);

    if(i == 0) {
      headNode = endNode = newNode;
    }
    else {
      endNode = appendNode(endNode, newNode);
    }
  }

  backwards = backwardsList(headNode, digits);

  displayNodes(backwards);
  displayNodes(headNode);
  freeNodes(headNode);
  freeNodes(backwards); // no need for this statement right? 
}

struct Digits* backwardsList(struct Digits* headNode, int digits) {
  struct Digits* headNodeCpy = headNode, * endNode, * newNode;

  for(int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
    newNode = createNode(headNodeCpy->digit);
    headNodeCpy = headNodeCpy->next;

    if(i == 0) endNode = newNode;
    else endNode = appendNodeFront(newNode, endNode);
  }

  return endNode;
}

struct Digits* appendNodeFront(struct Digits* newNode, struct Digits* endNode) {
  newNode->next = endNode;

  return newNode->next;
}

void freeNodes(struct Digits* headNode) {
  int i = 0;
  struct Digits* headNodeCpy = headNode;
  struct Digits* tmp;

  while(headNodeCpy != NULL) {
    tmp = headNodeCpy->next;
    free(headNodeCpy);
    headNodeCpy = NULL;
    if(headNodeCpy == NULL) printf("Node %d cleared\n", i);
    else printf("Error, node %d not cleared\n", i);
    headNodeCpy = tmp;
    i++;
  }

printf("\n");
}

void displayNodes(struct Digits* headNode) {
  struct Digits* headNodeCpy = headNode;

  while(headNodeCpy != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", headNodeCpy->digit);
    headNodeCpy = headNodeCpy->next;
  }

  printf("\n");
}

struct Digits* appendNode(struct Digits* endNode, struct Digits* newNode) {
  endNode->next = newNode;

  return endNode->next;
}

struct Digits* createNode(int digits) {
  struct Digits* newNode;

  newNode = (struct Digits*)malloc(sizeof(struct Digits));

  newNode->digit = digits;
  newNode->next = NULL;

  return newNode;
}
```

I think that the error occurs in the `backwardsList()` function, because i didn't set the "end" of this backwards list like i do up in `main()`.

Function where the error might occurs:

```c
struct Digits* backwardsList(struct Digits* headNode, int digits) {
  struct Digits* headNodeCpy = headNode, * endNode, * newNode;

  for(int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
    newNode = createNode(headNodeCpy->digit);
    headNodeCpy = headNodeCpy->next;

    if(i == 0) endNode = newNode;
    else endNode = appendNodeFront(newNode, endNode);
  }

  return endNode;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: try to debug your code since segmentation fault likely to happen almost every segment of your code.

Comment: I've read a document about debugging with gdb but i don't understand anything

Comment: okay then, just print something to the console in your functions that you are calling in main. For instance, print something in your ```backwardsList``` function before the loop and after the loop.

Comment: If you think ```backwardsList```  function is the problem, then in your ```main``` print something before calling the  ```backwardsList``` and after.

Comment: Il try to do that then

Comment: it seems like that insinde of `backwardsList` the LAST node is creating this error.

Comment: `  if(i == 0) endNode = newNode;
    else endNode = appendNodeFront(newNode, endNode);
  }` this is the error maker in this case then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243902/discussion-between-ali-ziya-cevk-and-i-y-s-z).

Comment: There are many (over 300) questions that get listed with an SO search term '`[c] reverse linked list is:q`'.  At least one of those should be able to help you sort out your trouble.

Comment: I suggest that [How to reverse a singly-linked list using only two pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1801549/15168) is worth studying.  Look at the answers with the highest scores and the check mark — they're the ones most worth study.