# Queue that uses a Stack

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I am having trouble understanding a question. The question asks first to write a C++ class to represent a stack of integers, and that much is done. Here are my prototypes:

```
class Stack{
private:
    int top;
    int item[100];
public:
    Stack() {top = -1;}
    ~Stack();
    void push(int x) {item[++top] = x;}
    int pop() {return item[top--];}
    int empty(int top);
};
```

The second part of the question says "Using the stack for storage purposes, write a C++ class to represent a queue of integers". My queue is as follows:

```
class Queue{
private:
    int * data;
    int beginning, end, itemCount;
public:
    Queue(int maxSize = 100);
    Queue(Queue &OtherQueue);
    ~Queue();
    void enqueue(int x);
    void dequeue();
    int amount();
};
```

I don't understand how I am meant to use a stack for storage purposes for a queue.

Comment: The question seems odd. A stack is a LIFO (last in, first out) structure while a queue normally is FIFO (first in, first out) structure. Unless you have to implement a LIFO queue it is hard to use a stack.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688276/implement-stack-using-two-queues

Comment: I don't think you meant to have your Stack constructor as you have it. Perhaps you meant "Stack() {top = -1;}"?

Comment: @KM what's the point of this site, if not to ask questions?

Comment: Re:KM, Because the only answer we can give you is the assignment doesn't make sense. You can't use a stack as a queue.

Comment: We've been saying this about teachers for years, but teachers still give out assignments that don't make sense.  Don't think that's going to change anytime soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree with the existing answer. *Typically*, a queue is [First In First Out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_%28computing%29), while a stack is obviously [Last In First Out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29). I can only think of an implementation using two stacks, popping the whole thing and adding all but the last item to the second stack.

Seems like a silly thing to do, but I guess it's for the sake of the exercise. As commented below, it is possible to do in [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) O(1), because the second stack will be in the right order. You can just take elements from the second stack, until you run out, in which case you move everything from the original stack to the second stack.

A FIFO queue would just be a stack with `Enqueue` being `Push` and `Dequeue` being `Pop`. That doesn't make any sense as an exercise, so I'd definitely assume a FIFO queue was intended.

*Edit*: added some links, something not easily done on my phone :)

Comment: This appears to be a common interview question, asked by retard interviewers.

Comment: It does make sense as an exercise, because it shows how one can use simple data structures to create more complex ones. By using two stacks in a sensible way one can create a queue with *O(1)* `enqueue` and `dequeue` operations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294756/queue-that-uses-a-stack/1294845#1294845

Comment: There is no "sensible" way of using two stacks to implement a queue. The sensible way is to use a deque, list or vector.

Comment: @Stephan202: True, but it still seems a little artificial. A queue is much easier to implement with just an array, and it would just be O(1) (non-amortized).

Comment: @Stephan202: it's not actually `O(1)`. But it is *amortized* `O(1)`.

Comment: @Thorarin: an array based queue is not actually `O(1)` either. Once you fill the array, you have to reallocate it, which is `O(n)`. This is like a hash table.

Comment: There's no need to reallocate the array, unless you need to grow it in size. The original stack implementation was also fixed size, so I assumed that was okay. If it needs to be resizing, it would be amortized O(1).

Answer (score 10):

Take two stacks, *in* and *out*.

- To `enqueue` an element, `push` it on stack *in*.
- To `dequeue` an element,

  1. `pop` an element from stack *out* if *out* is not empty; otherwise,
  2. `pop` and `push` all elements from *in* to *out*, then serve the top element of *out*.

It is important that you perform step 2 only if necessary. Note that `enqueue` has complexity *O(1)*, and `dequeue` has [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) complexity *O(1)*, provided your implementations of `pop` and `push` are *O(1)*.

Comment: Good point, Nick! I have updated the answer. (Did you just remove and then re-add your comment? It was gone for a short while...)

Comment: What do you mean by "sensible", a word you seem far too fond of?

Comment: It is not clear that I refer to `push` and `pop` implementations which have O(1) complexity?

Comment: I removed the word "sensible". Just for you, Neil.

Comment: OK, so what data structure are you using that gives you O(1) for push and pop? The obvious answer is a doubly linked list. In which case why not use one such list to implement the queue that the question is about?

Comment: I am not disputing that there are better ways to implement a queue than using two stacks. However, the OP wants to know how to do this, and that is what my answer addresses. To be clear: I agree with you that the OP's assignment is contrived.

Comment: The best answer to give to a question is always the most direct, correct solution. If the questioner doesn't like it, tough.

Answer (score 4):

Queue's private data must be a Stack. With that only you can of course trivially
implement a LIFO queue only; for a FIFO queue you need TWO stacks -- to quote the
hint for exercise 10 at this excellent [page](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/43stack/), "Hint: If you push elements onto a stack and then pop them all, they appear in reverse order. If you repeat this process, they're now back in order."...

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it wouldn't be the recommended method of storage, since one is LIFO and the other is FIFO.

To queue, you would push your integer onto the stack.

To dequeue, you would have to pop all integers off the stack, get the last integer, and push all other integers back onto the stack. Have a temporary stack where you push all the integers as you pop them off, get your answer, then pop all integers off the temporary stack back onto your main storage.

Answer (score 2):

Queue with stack? You will need 2 stacks, of course that would be a O(n) queue implementation.

Comment: +0. Yes, you need two stacks. No, the implementation will not necessarily be *O(n)*. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294756/queue-that-uses-a-stack/1294845#1294845

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a stack and a queue is in a stack you both add and remove items from the top, whereas in a queue you add at the top and remove from the bottom.  So to implement a queue using a stack, the enqueue operation will be a normal push on the stack, while the dequeue operation will have to pop the entire stack, retrieve the last item, then push all the items back on the stack.  You'll have to use another stack to store the items temporarily.

Comment: You don't have to shuffle back and forth. Once things are on the "dequeue" stack, they can stay there until the stack is empty.

Comment: Until you have to add more items to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the intent of the question is to first define a class Stack as you have which has the capacity to store ints.

then declare a class inherited from stack called Queue which has it's own addtoqueue and servefromqueue functions but uses the same storage mechanism as Stack.

Given your implementation this may seem a little strange, but they probably intended some kind of linked list implementation of the stack (which has the advantage of not having a predefined upper limit) in which case the queue inherited from stack makes clear design sense.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that "using **the** stack for storage purposes" means use the stack instead of the heap.   That is, don't call malloc, and don't use global variables.

Edit: Or maybe not.  The more I think about this, the more I suspect it's a poorly worded, or poorly thought out assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to implement a queue using a stack you could add a `Stack` member variable to the `Queue` class. The methods are then implemented like this:

```
void Queue::enqueue(int value) {
  stack.push(value);
}

int Queue::dequeue() {
  // TODO: Check for empty queue.
  Stack tempStack;
  do {
    tempStack.push(stack.pop());
  } while (!stack.empty());
  int value = tempStack.pop();
  while (!tempStack.empty()) {
    stack.push(tempStack.pop());
  }
  return value;
}
```

It is a very inefficient implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So really, it's a matter of giving a stack input and then taking out information from that stack as if it were a que.

I dont think that you need to pop ALL of the integers off of the stack. Are you allowed to use any other methods for the stack? I mean, based on x86, you can always obtain elements on a stack based on their address.

In this sense, you can always get the first element on the que by retrieving the 'first-in' data member which will always be at the first index of the array within the stack data structure (as represented in your prototype).

So - since the stack is LIFO and the que is FIFO, use that to your advantage since the que data structure is dependent on the stack data structure. If you can, include a method that allows the retrieval of the first element on 'top' of the stack (which would be the element @ index 0).

Make sure that this is ok with your professor first though.

Answer (score -1):

There are different types of queues:

- [First in - first out (FIFO) queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_%28computing%29)
- [Last in - first out (LIFO) queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29)

If your queue is a LIFO queue, than it merely becomes a facade of a stack where enque/deque map to push/pop.

If you want a FIFO queue you will need two stacks and shift the elements from one to the others in order to get to the first element when it is enqued, then you can deque from the top of the second stack (which is in reverse order) as long as nothing else is enqued. if that happens you ned to shift everything back to the first stack... Not very efficient but maybe realizing that is the point of the exercise...

NB: you might want to at least make the max capacity of your stack configurable at construction time. Making it entirely dynamic is probably out of the scope of the excercise you are trying to solve.

Answer (score -2):

A queue is a stack of integers in your instance.  You add integers to the stack and remove them from the stack.