# Name three strategies for internal data storage when implementing a Stack ADT

Tags: c#, arrays, list, stack, abstract-data-type

This was a question my Data Structures teacher put on our recent test.  I immediately thought of a List and an Array but I cannot for the life of me think of a third ADT that could be used as internal storage for a Stack.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is a third option.

```
class MyStack<T>
{
    LinkedList<T> linkedList = new LinkedList<T>();

    public void Push(T t)
    {
        linkedList.AddFirst(t);
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        T result = linkedList.First.Value;
        linkedList.RemoveFirst();
        return result;
    }
}
```

It's also possible (but not generally useful) to [implement a stack using two queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688276/implement-stack-using-two-queues).

Comment: I realize now that the question is tagged with C#.  However, from the data structure point of view a Linked List is a List.

Answer (score 0):

List,Array,Tree,Graph

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only 2 possible way to [implement a queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29#Implementation):

- array
- linked list

A third way would probably be a mix of the 2:

- linked list of arrays.