# Is there a characterization of algorithms that doesn't have a recursive form?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

This question arises from the binary tree representations(preorder, postorder, level order, etc.).Some of them can be written in a recursive form(preorder representation, for example), but I don't think there is a recursive algorithm for the level order representation(Or if you know how to do that please tell me!). So my question is: Is there a "type" of algorithms that cannot be written in recursive form? If so, how can this type of algorithms be characterized?(Or is there a system in which you can write a proof that certain algorithm cannot be written in a recursive way?)

Comment: As I know, all loops can be turned into a recursive form.

Comment: Related: [Performing Breadth First Search recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2549541/1639625)

Comment: Loops and recursion are computationally equivalent. There is no algorithm that can be implemented recursively that cannot also be implemented iteratively, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, here's the full characterisation. The set of algorithms that cannot be expressed recursively is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't necessarily think that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093618/can-all-iterative-algorithms-be-expressed-recursively), but it's a great reference.  It provides a proof stating that every iterative algorithm can be written recursively.  For that reason, there would be no category of algorithms which doesn't have a recursive form.

Answer (score 0):

```
while Condition do Statement end
```

can be equivalently written

```
to Perform():
    if Condition then Statement; Perform() end
```

and all sequential programs can be rewritten recursively, without loops.

Comment: Recursion is just your langauge's runtime maintaining a call stack for you. You can always replace recursion with iteration by maintaining that stack yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion follows from a base case. If the final result follows from a base case then the algorithm has a recursive form. Recursive algorithms usually take the form `F(n) = G( F(n-1 ) ... )` Example is Fibonacci series.
`F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)`. This naturally falls into recursive form.

Your question seems to be more about implementation of an algorithm.
Every recursive algorithm can be implemented both recursively and non-recursively.
Because recursion inherently uses a function stack. The same stack you could use explicitly in the non-recursive form of implementation.

Therefore you could easily implement pre-order, post-order, in-order using both recursive and non-recursive forms.

Coming to level order, I am sure you could implement that in recursive form as well. For example ( may not be in its fully correct form ).

```
void printLevelOrder( int level, Queue<Node> q ) {

    if ( !q.isEmpty() ) {
      Node curr = q.peek();
      int size = q.size();
      System.out.print( "At level " + level + " : " );
      for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
         System.out.println( q.poll().toString() );
      }
      for ( Node child : curr.children() ) {
        q.add( child );
      }
    }
    printLevelOrder( level + 1, q );
 }
```

But the point is implementation and mathematical form of algorithm are different.