# compare a string with 1st line in a file

Tags: python, file

For some reason it comes as false. I used the comparison operator. The file works properly. There seem to be an issue with the comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performing Breadth First Search recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549541/performing-breadth-first-search-recursively)

Comment: First we read the documentation - here’s a good place to start to find built-in functions https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html and there you will find `open()`. Also see this topic about reading and writing files https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files - and have a good browse around the documentation because it’s full of useful information about Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the file and load its contents like this:

```
def open_file():
    with open("filename", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
```

Call the function with `all_lines = open_file()`

Then read line by line with:

```
for line in all_lines:
    Print(line)
```

Comment: no no I got that, I mean like first line of file with an input string. For some reason when i used the == (they were the same), it comes as false.

Comment: @Power123 you need to include the example in your question. Please read the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        ... do stuff with line ...
```