# Weird performance of list reversal in Python

Tags: python, list

I run this script and I don't understand how the list reversal works.

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._push_stack = list()
        self._pop_stack = list()


    def push(self, x):
        self._push_stack.append(x)
        self._pop_stack.append(x)
        self._pop_stack.reverse()
        print(self._push_stack, self._pop_stack) # debugging


    def pop(self):
        if len(self._pop_stack) == 0:
            raise IndexError("pop from an empty queue")
        else:
            self._push_stack.pop()
            return self._pop_stack.pop()


queue = Queue()
queue.push(3)
queue.push(5)
queue.push(7)
queue.push(9)
print(queue.pop())
print(queue.pop())
print(queue.pop())
print(queue.pop())
```

The output for this script is:

```
[3] [3]
[3, 5] [5, 3]
[3, 5, 7] [7, 3, 5]
[3, 5, 7, 9] [9, 5, 3, 7]
7
3
5
9
```

What I don't understand is why `[3, 5, 7]`, when reversed, is `[7, 3, 5]` and not `[7, 5, 3]`; why `[3, 5, 7, 9]`, when reversed, is `[9, 5, 3, 7]`, and not  `[9, 7, 5, 3]`.

PS please ignore other shortcomings of the script.

Comment: You are reversing the order of `pop_stack` after each element you add - that causes some very strange order of elements

Comment: Have you tried to debug code?

Comment: I don't know what explanation you want that your weird code and the debugging output does not already demonstrate. You keep flipping the order of `self._pop_stack`, so it ends up in a weird order.

Comment: Ignoring the other shortcomings of the script ignores the reason for this behaviour..

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) After the second iteration, you have `push: [3, 5] pop: [5, 3]`. Then you append 7 to each list, so you have `push: [3, 5, 7] pop: [5, 3, 7]`. Then you reverse `pop`, so you have `push: [3, 5, 7] pop: [7, 3, 5]`. Your debug output already tells you this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reverse the pop stack each time, which is bad. After the second push, you have `[5, 3]`, then you append 7, leaving `[5, 3, 7]`, then you reverse it, giving you `[7, 3, 5]`.

You don't need to reverse every time, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2050402/5923139) answer for an explanation on how to properly implement the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are reversing the list at every iteration after the append operation, this is causing the list to be `[3,5]` before 7 is appended and then reversed

Answer (score 0):

This  is because you are not reversing `[3, 5, 7]` but `[5, 3, 7]` if you take a closer look at your code you are reversing the pop_stack every time you push an item. Instead of that you should be prepending:

instead of

```
self._pop_stack.append(x)
self._pop_stack.reverse()
```

You can use:
`self._pop_stack.insert(0, x)`