# stack related question in microprocessor

Tags: microprocessors

can we also do queue operations in microprocessor? (given that the microprocessor supports stack operations )

Comment: somebody edit this question please..

Comment: @Srinivas, I'd like to, but I don't understand what's asked here...

Comment: what she is asking is there is  an inbuilt  stack in microprocessor,so along the same lines is there a queue also?

Answer (score 2):

No. The stack is built in insofar as there's a register and operations to support it. There is no similar support for a queue.

If you want a queue, you need to implement it in code.

Answer (score 0):

### Have stack, want Queue??...

---

You can always implement queues in software. Refer this Q for more:

> - [StackOverflow.com/questions/69192/using-stack-as-queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192/using-stack-as-queue)

For a detailed discussion on how to **implement a queue** using stacks:

> - [GeeksforGeeks.org/?p=5009](http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=5009)

GoodLUCK!!