# implements expected here error

Tags: java

hey, i have to create a `TwoStacksQueue.java` that creates a queue using two stacks.

i just want to know how to implement `Stack.java` into `TwoStacksQueue.java`.

this is what i have:

```
public class TwoStacksQueue<Item> implements Stack<Item>
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192/using-stack-as-queue

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to implement a queue by using two stacks your class should be defined as a Queue. Then the internal representation is up to you. Maybe something like this:

```
public class TwoStacksQueue<Item> implements Queue<Item> {

private Stack stack1;
private Stack stack2;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'd want to `implements` a Stack. If you're going to use two stacks, you'll want something like this

```
public class TwoStacksQueue<E> {

    Stack<E> firstStack;
    Stack<E> secondStack;

}
```