# How to analyze complexity of a program that behavior might change under different situation?

Tags: time-complexity, code-complexity

When I came across this question - [using two stacks to implement a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192/how-to-implement-a-queue-using-two-stacks), I'm wondering how to analyze complexity of it.

Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69436/558892) as example:

- For queue(), the complexity is always O(1), as it simply push into the inbox.
- For dequeue(), most of the time the complexity is also O(1), but when outbox is empty, it needs a loop to move all elements from inbox to outbox. So what is the complexity of this operation?

What is the idea when analyzing such kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

As Dave L. states in his explanation "each element will be pushed twice and popped twice, giving amortized constant time operations". This is because each dequeue that needs to move n elements from one stack to the other (taking O(n) time) will be followed by n-1 dequeues that only take O(1) time.

So one way to express the complexity of `dequeue()` would be saying that it has amortized constant time with a best cas of O(1) and a worst case of O(n).