# Implement a singly linked list using 2 stack only

Tags: stack, singly-linked-list, forward-list

An interviewer asked me yesterday how to implemented a singly linked list using 2 (two) stack objects while keeping the **same time complexity of a singly linked list**.

Do you have any idea how this could be done?

*PS: I may have misunderstood the question in some way, so please tell me if you know about a 'classic' case that is somehow similar to th*is.

Hope the question was clear.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I just found this similar question: [How to implement a queue using two stacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192/how-to-implement-a-queue-using-two-stacks?rq=1)

I think I can answer my question based on the solution described in the top answer there.