# Suppose you use a stack instead of a queue when running breadth-first search. Does it still compute shortest paths?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

can I use stack instead of a queue when
running breadth-first search. Does it still compute shortest paths?

Comment: If you use a stack, it won't be breadth-first, it will be depth-first.

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible.

Yes, you can surely use *stacks* instead of a queue as the auxiliary data structure for the Breadth-First Search.

That said, I am talking about **implementing a queue using 2 stacks**. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69436/1866196) answer for a short explanation.

For every enqueue and dequeue operation, you might have to perform some extra pushing and popping which may lead to a complex code for a simple BFS.

If you are restricted to using **just 1 stack**, you might as well try for a Depth-First Search.